# How can I make an enemy stop for a second after colliding with the player? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

After the enemy collides with the player I want him to stop for some time, so it doesnt chase after him all the time. It looks weird. Like, add an Invoke function or something(not a pro). Please implement it right away (im just a beginner) Here is the code(I was following some 7 hour tutorial):

```
// Experience
public int xpValue = 1;

//Particle system
public GameObject effect;

// Logic
public float triggerLength = 1;
public float chaseLength = 5;
public bool chasing;
public bool collidingWithPlayer;
private Transform playerTransform;
private Vector3 startingPosition;

// Hitbox
public ContactFilter2D filter;
private BoxCollider2D hitbox;
private Collider2D[] hits = new Collider2D[10];

protected override void Start()
{
    base.Start();
    playerTransform = GameManager.instance.player.transform;
    startingPosition = transform.position;
    hitbox = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}

protected void FixedUpdate(){
    //Is the player in range?
    if(Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, startingPosition) < chaseLength)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, startingPosition) < triggerLength)
        chasing = true;

        if (chasing){
            if(!collidingWithPlayer){
                UpdateMotor((playerTransform.position - transform.position).normalized);
            }
        }
        else{
            UpdateMotor(startingPosition - transform.position);
        }
    }
    else{
        UpdateMotor(startingPosition - transform.position);
        chasing = false;
    }

    //Check for overlap
    collidingWithPlayer = false;
    boxCollider.OverlapCollider(filter, hits); // null reference expection
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hits[i] == null)\

            continue;

            if(hits[i].tag == "Fighter" && hits[i].name == "Player"){
                collidingWithPlayer = true;
            }

        //this array is not cleaned up, so we do it ourself
        hits[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all the protected statements? You dont need to override start. What have you tried to add any formnof delay?

Comment: @BugFinder if there is a common base class which is not `MonoBehaviour` it is not unusual to implement the Unity message methods as `protected virtual` in order to be able to safely `override` them without hiding the base implementation and causing issues where the Unity framework doesn't call the base methods etc

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use either Coroutines or timers to achieve this.
This is untested and there is likely some optimization that can be done on this.

Timers

```
private bool hasAttacked = false;

private float attackTimer = 0;
private float waitTime = 0.5f;

private void Update()
{
   if (!hasAttacked)
   {
      hasAttacked = true;
      attack();
      attackTimer = Time.time + waitTime;
   }
   else
   {
      if ( Time.time > attackTimer)
      {
         hasAttacked = false;
      }
   }
}
```

This snippet will run an attack function, then wait for 0.5 seconds, and run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to look into coroutines. They run on the main thread but can be paused and wait for delays or events.

```
bool CanAttack()
{
    return true; //Check if can attack here
}

void Attack()
{
    //Put your attacking code here
}

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(AttackLoop());
}

IEnumerator AttackLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Check if enemy can attack
        if (CanAttack())
        {
            Attack();
            //Waits 2 seconds before continuing
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        }

        //Wait one frame
        //Prevents an infinite loop
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this is working. Can you implement what you weote in my code. Im just a beginner, would appreciate it!!!